# trigger function in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to make a trigger function that will check if on insert/update of a record of event date the information is valid:

```
create or replace function trigf() returns trigger as $$
declare bad_date record;
begin
     select festival.title into bad_date
     from festival
     where new.title = festival.title and (new.edate < festival.sdate or new.edate > festival.edate);

     if exists bad_date then
                 raise notice 'Error: Event Date does not Correlate with the Festival.';
                if T = 'insert' then return null;
                    else return old;
                        end if;
         else
             return new;
         end if;
 end;
 $$language plpgsql;

 create trigger T
 before insert or update on event
 for each row
 execute procedure trigf();
```

compilation passes fine but when trying to insert values I get an error that bad_date does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of:

```
declare bad_date record;

if exists bad_date then
```

Should be:

```
declare bad_date text; -- or same type of festival.title 

if bad_date IS NOT NULL then
```